Не отображается pwd в строке ввода команды (Ubuntu)
Имею в виду зелёный текст. Его нет у только что созданного пользователя (2 скриншот) в отличие от пользователя, созданного при установке ОС (1 скриншот). Какой пакет (или строка(и) в .bashrc) отвечают за это поведение?



Ну для начала логичный вопрос — а это хоть bash вообще?) Внутренний телепат подсказывает мне, что при создании пользователя вы в качестве шелла по умолчанию указали банальный sh


как указал @andreymal в комментарии, дело действительно может быть в


в качестве шелла по умолчанию указали банальный sh


в .bashrc есть переменная PS1. Соответственно, выглядит зачастую строкой PS1=' ' (между кавычками может быть различный набор, в зависимости от желаемого вида).
В целом, эту строку можно как просто скопировать в .bashrc другого пользователя, так и можно при желании изменить вид строки (цвет, добавить/убрать отображение времени, директории и т.д.). Если интересно, то про изменение этой переменной есть статья на Хабре

